# Retrieving the IDs of entries to be deleted from a table

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-core

## Business logic

It would take us too far to explain the whole business case behind this code, so I'll try to be as succinct as possible.

- There are `Person`s,
- and Persons can have `Profile`s,
- and the combination of those two is a `PersonProfile`.
- There is also a table called `ProfilesToReplace`, which contains `Profile`s that in the future will be replaced by updated ones.

  - For compatibility sake these `ProfilesToReplace` are not linked to the actual `Person`, but to a "dummy" `Person`.

Over time, entries in `ProfilesToReplace` will be deleted (once an outdated `Profile` has been replaced by a proper one), which means the related `Profile`s need to be removed. But before that can happen, we need to remove the `PersonProfile`s that link to these outdated `Profile`s and remove these first. We also need to remove the "dummy" `Person`s once they have no related entries in the `PersonProfile`s table.

This is done via a regularly running job, which is a .NET C# 4.6.2 command line application (but it uses the new csproj format).

## The problem

There is however a snag. To know which `Person` is a "dummy" person, we need to look at that `Person`'s IDF: in the case of a "dummy" `Person`, it is the same as the IDF of its related "real" `Person`, except for a single digit. We do have a list of "real" IDFs, but that is in another database, and it is not possible to connect our database to that other database.

The good news: we can retrieve a list of these "valid" IDFs in our application. The bad news: this involves tens of thousands of IDFs, and thus we're confronted with the limits of SQL Server parameters. Moreover, we're working with [EntityFrameworkCore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) and I haven't found a way to pass a list of data via [`.FromSql()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). Also, retrieving all data and filtering in code is problematic as well, since `PersonProfile`s contains more than a million records.

## How I solved it

However, I found a way around these issues, allowing me to do the filtering in a query: I pass the list of IDFs as an XML string and let the query untangle it into a list of IDFs that can be used in a WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [Id]

FROM [authorization].[PersonProfile]

WHERE 1 = 1
    AND [ProfileId] NOT IN (
        SELECT [ProfileId]
        FROM [authorization].[ProfilesToReplace]
    )
    AND [PersonIdf] IN (
        SELECT PersonIdf
        FROM (
            SELECT PersonIdf = XTbl.value('(PersonIdf)[1]', 'bigint')
            FROM @PersonIdfs.nodes('/root') AS XD(XTbl)
        ) AS XmlToData
    )
```

And this is how I use that SQL and pass it the necessary parameter:

```cs
public async Task<ICollection<int?>> Execute(List<long> dummyPersonIdfs)
{
    var getDeletablePersonProfilesQuery = QueryRetriever.GetQuery("GetDeletablePersonProfiles.sql");
    var personIdfsAsXml = new XDocument(
            new XElement("root", dummyPersonIdfs.Select(x => new XElement("PersonIdf", x))))
        .ToString();
    var personIdfs = new SqlParameter("@PersonIdfs", SqlDbType.Xml) { Value = personIdfsAsXml };
    var deletablePersonProfileIds = (await _dbContext.DeletablePersonProfiles
            .FromSql(getDeletablePersonProfilesQuery, personIdfs).ToListAsync())
        .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    if (deletablePersonProfileIds.Any())
    {
        return await _personsRemover.Execute(deletablePersonProfileIds);
    }

    return new List<int?>();
}
```

`QueryRetriever` is simply a class that retrieves the above SQL query from an embedded .sql file:

```cs
internal static class QueryRetriever
{
    public static string GetQuery(string scriptName)
    {
        var namespacePrefix = "Badger.Service.BadgeCleaning.";
        var resourceName = namespacePrefix + scriptName;
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Missing SQL script: {resourceName}");
            }

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## So all's well?

While I am happy with the code as is, I'm wondering whether I've made it more complicated than needs to be. Am I overlooking a simpler solution?

I'm also somewhat unsure of how I construct the XML string: is there perhaps a more efficient way?

And is the way I deal with the XML string in my SQL query the best way? Note that I cannot use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql), because the application isn't currently running on SQL Server 2016 (or any more recent product).

Answer (score 2):

If you weren't using EntityFrameworkCore, my suggestion would look something like this:

1. Get the list of values from database 1
2. Use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert a bunch of them into some table on database 2
3. Join to that table in your "GetDeletablePersonProfiles" query.

Unfortunately, based on some cursory googling, it looks like EntityFrameworkCore [doesn't support bulk operations](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7256) ([this extension](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) does, however). I'll admit - I don't know a ton about EFC, but based on what you're doing I assume the following is possible:

1. Get the list of values from database 1 (you're already doing this)
2. In the code you execute, dump the values from the XML into a table (better performance than joining to the XML)
3. Use that table in your query

Specifically, the main change I would suggest is taking this:

```
AND [PersonIdf] IN (
    SELECT PersonIdf
    FROM (
        SELECT PersonIdf = XTbl.value('(PersonIdf)[1]', 'bigint')
        FROM @PersonIdfs.nodes('/root') AS XD(XTbl)
    ) AS XmlToData
)
```

And turn it into this (you'll notice that I've also transformed both of your `EXISTS` into `JOIN`s; they're easier to read and accomplish the same task.

```
SELECT PersonIdf = XTbl.value('(PersonIdf)[1]', 'bigint')
  INTO #MyFunTempTable
  FROM @PersonIdfs.nodes('/root') AS XD(XTbl);

SELECT DISTINCT PersonProfile.[Id]
  FROM [authorization].[PersonProfile]
    INNER JOIN #MyFunTempTable PersonIdfList
      ON PersonProfile.PersonIdf = PersonIdfList.PersonIdf
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [authorization].[ProfilesToReplace]
      ON PersonProfile.ProfileId = ProfilesToReplace.ProfileId
  WHERE ProfilesToReplace.ProfileId IS NULL
```

It would also be good to make this a stored procedure, so that you don't have to worry about GetDeletablePersonProfiles.sql being replaced by a malicious actor.

You could also split it into two stages, using `ExecuteSqlCommand` to insert the values into a table (can't be a temp table anymore) and then you should really just need LINQ to get the values back.

You can also get an ADO.NET `DbConnection` object from the database context using `_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()`, and if you know that this is a SQL Server connection I've heard that you can cast that to a `SqlConnection` object, at which point you have access to the `SqlBulkCopy` method. This is questionable at best, but it might provide clean enough/performant enough code to be worthwhile. I'm definitely not endorsing this approach, but I'll put it out there.