# Indentation for c# functions

Tags: c#

I am just looking to improve my indentation on my current code. I'd be happy to hear any reviews and improvements.

```
public class DataAccess
{

    public List<ComplaintModel> GetComplaint(string _OrderNumber)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void InsertComplaint(
        DateTime _Date,
        string _OrderNumber,
        string _CustomerName,
        string _CustomerContactName,
        string _Telephone,
        string _Email,
        string _CustomerReference,
        string _Product,
        string _PackSize,
        string _BatchNumber,
        DateTime _BestBeforeDate,
        string _QuantityInvolved,
        string _Details, 
        string _Comments)
    {
        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            List<ComplaintModel> complaint = new List<ComplaintModel>();

            complaint.Add(new ComplaintModel { Date = _Date,
                OrderNumber = _OrderNumber,
                CustomerName = _CustomerName,
                CustomerContactName = _CustomerContactName,
                Telephone = _Telephone,
                Email = _Email,
                CustomerReference = _CustomerReference,
                Product = _Product,
                PackSize = _PackSize,
                BatchNumber = _BatchNumber,
                BestBeforeDate = _BestBeforeDate,
                QuantityInvolved = _QuantityInvolved,
                Details = _Details,
                Comments = _Comments});

            conn.Execute(@"INSERT INTO customer_complaints 
                        (date_taken, order_number, customer_name, customer_contact, telephone, email, customer_reference, product, pack_size, batch_lot_number,
                        best_before_date, quantity_involved, details, comments) 
                        VALUES (@Date, @OrderNumber, @CustomerName, @CustomerContactName, @Telephone, @Email, @CustomerReference, @Product, @PackSize, @BatchNumber,
                        @BestBeforeDate, @QuantityInvolved, @Details, @Comments)", complaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 more things, Object-Modeling (passing a model to the `InsertComplaint` method. Secondly, using `ORM`. If you use an ORM like Dapper and Entity Framework, then your work would be much simpler and you would avoid most of SQL-Injections risks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two places where I would use `var`:

```
var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString)
var complaint = new List<ComplaintModel>();
```

You no longer have to put braces around a using block, saving you one indentation level:

```
using var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString);
```

Don't put the first parameter at the end of the line and the rest on a new line. Put the first parameter on a new line as well:

```
complaint.Add(new ComplaintModel {
    Date = _Date,
    ...
```

If you start the Query string on a new line, you can move it back one indentation level:

```
conn.Execute(
    @"INSERT INTO customer_complaints
    ...
```

Comment: Be careful with removing braces from `using` statements. While in this scenario it doesn't hurt, there might be other scenarios where it leads to unexpected results, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61761053/3502980) that I've answered a while back

Answer (score 3):

Dennis_E has some good advice, but there are two items I would do differently.

1. The SQL insert statement looks fine as-is. The code reads just fine, but I would declare a private constant in the class to store the statement.
2. Put the curly braces for your object initializer on their own lines as well:

   ```
   complaint.Add(new ComplaintModel     
   {
       Date = _Date,
       OrderNumber = _OrderNumber,
       CustomerName = _CustomerName,
       CustomerContactName = _CustomerContactName,
       Telephone = _Telephone,
       Email = _Email,
       CustomerReference = _CustomerReference,
       Product = _Product,
       PackSize = _PackSize,
       BatchNumber = _BatchNumber,
       BestBeforeDate = _BestBeforeDate,
       QuantityInvolved = _QuantityInvolved,
       Details = _Details,
       Comments = _Comments
   });
   ```

Some additional observations unrelated to indentation:

- Rename your parameters to camelCase instead of PascalCase with leading underscores. The idiomatic naming convention in C# would be `quantityInvolved` rather than `_QuantityInvolved`.

  It might sound insignificant, but reaching for the shift key and/or the underscore key slows down your typing speed. It is "death by a thousand paper cuts." One tiny little decrease in speed by itself doesn't matter. Multiply that by the hundreds of times each day you do this while typing code and it adds up.

Comment: Totally agree with the underscore aha! :D

Comment: The General Naming Conventions also discourage the use of underscores (_) : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions
I personally like the _ on members to distinguish from function and class scope, but that's a personal preference. The coreFx (net core) Coding Guidelines Agree: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md so not even MS is consistent

Answer (score 0):

You have a method with fourteen parameters, this is way too many. The names of these parameters also don't follow the one usually used in C#: camelCased, and no underscore prefix.

Why not construct a `ComplaintModel` and pass that to `InsertComplaint()`?

---

`DataAccess` is IMHO a far too generic name. You'll be tempted to fill this with dozens of methods, centralizing all of your database logic there, and it will just become unmanageable. Consider having a "ComplaintsService" for instance where you just have the methods related to complaints, or even go full [CQRS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs).

---

Do not pointlessly abbreviate names. I can live with `conn` (though I'd prefer `mySqlConnection`), but `ConnString` is pointless. I get that you did this to avoid issues with the class named `ConnectionString`, but then you should change that class's name.

---

Give things proper names: `List<ComplaintModel> complaint` is wrong because it is literally a list of complaints, and thus it should be called `complaints`.

---

I'm not a fan of inline SQL when it becomes lengthy. I'm a fan of embedding .SQL scripts and then reading them [using a QueryRetriever](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214250/retrieving-the-ids-of-entries-to-be-deleted-from-a-table). The advantage is that such .SQL scripts also become color-coded in Visual Studio (though I wish there was a way to have different extensions based on the type of query, e.g. SQL Server vs. MySql vs Oracle etc.).